# Modular forms and number of representations by binary quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x,y)$ be a positive definite quadratic form of discriminant $d$. Let $r_Q(n)$ be the number of solutions of $Q(x,y)=n$. It is known that the function $f_Q(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_Q(n)q^n$ is a modular form of weight $1$. Let $Q_1,\ldots,Q_{h_d}$ be representatives for nonequivalent classes of forms of discriminant $D$. Then we have the formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^{h_d}r_{Q_k}(n)=\sum_{t\mid n}\chi_d(t).$$
I know how to prove this using ideals and $L$-series, or in an  elementary way. Is there a proof that uses the fact that $f_Q(\tau)$ is a modular form? Can you give me a reference?

Comment: This is theorem 64 on pages 78-79 of Dickson, (1929) Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. On pages 80-81 he does $x^2 +y^2$ and some other class number one forms. There is a coefficient $w$ we now call the Tamagawa number, defined in theorem 59 on page 75

Comment: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n1/mode/2up  you can read it online; if it lets me I will post pages

Comment: You need to show that $\sum_{k = 1}^{h_d} f_{Q_k}(\tau) = E^{\ast}(\tau,1/2,\chi_d)$, where the right-hand side is the completed Eisenstein series associated to $\chi_d$.

Answer (score 4):

The coefficient $w$ in theorem 64 is usually $2,$  but is $4$ for discriminant $-4,$ then $6$ for discriminant $-3$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I downloaded the book and will look into it. However, this does not answer my question; what I had in mind was rather a proof along the lines of the proof of two/four square theorem using the series $\sum q^{n^2}$.